# Lock() { ... } wait time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Let's say we have MethodA and MethodB where whole methods' bodies are within single big lock block. Both methods use the same object for locking:

```
lock (objectX) 
{ 
    // methodbody
}
```

There are multiple threads that call these two methods.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to measure total wait time? Including: time to obtain lock and time required by "other" method's lock block to finish execution.
2. Would it be faster to introduce locks in both methods on appropriate places instead of encapsulating whole method body with single lock? I realize that here i need to measure performance of both solutions, but I would like to hear your experience and recommendations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2) Would it be faster to introduce locks in both methods on appropriate places

Yes. Always keep locked segments as short as possible. The locking itself is cheap, dont keep others waiting while you do non-critical things.

> 1) Is it possible to measure total wait time? Including: time to obtain lock and time required by "other" method's lock block to finish execution.

Not this precisely I think. For long stretches you might look into CPU time vs Elapsed time but in general: use a good profiler.

Comment: "Always keep locked segments as short as possible." should really be "Keep locked segments as short as possible without introducing excessive lock contention", no?  Taking a lock is not a zero-cost operation.

Comment: @ChrisShain Monitor.Enter() is very cheap when there is no contention.  But yes, very small segments is not a good idea either. It's a trade-off between context-switching and needless waiting.

Comment: “Always keep locked segments as short as possible.” I think it's worth pointing out that you should never make the them shorter than that. If you need to make an operation atomic using `lock`, you need to include the whole operation into that `lock`, not split it into several segments.

Comment: Ok, I realize I have to measure performance because of potential lock contention.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, do You have any profiler suggestion? Because the one I tried with didn't show lock statement or Monitor.Enter, ... I just see that methods with lock statements take significantly longer than the sum of methods they called. I will try to use Monitor methods instead of lock statement to see if it will show in profiler then.

Comment: @Filip `lock()` _is_ `Monitor.Enter()`

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes, I realize that in the IL it will translate lock to Monitor.* methods. It was just blind shot to see if profiler will catch anything. Unfortunately, it will not. At least, not the one i use.